# What are the main parameters to check display with display controller

Tags: voltage, current, serial, display, deserialiser

I have [MAX9278](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9278-MAX9282.pdf) deserializer IC which is connected to a 3.1inch TFT display 800 (W) * 480 (H).

Deserializer provides 4 LVDS lanes and 1 clock to the display.

What are the major parameters that I need to check so that I can confirm that the Display will work fine with my deserializer?

Comment: To have a kernel driver, maybe?

Comment: How to check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video format compatibility, e.g. resolution, blanking, pixel clock. Interface compatibility between singe/double/quad LVDS link. For each of the links 8-bit display with 4 lanes, or 6-bit display with 3 lanes. Compatible link/lane bit mapping e.g. VESA or JEIDA. DE/HS/VS sync compatibility. Basically everything that is provided regarding the interfaces.